# FOP XSL 1.0 Replace text and keep line break

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to generate a pdf using xsl + xml, but Im having problems on a part of the document where there is some lines of text with line breaks.
When generating the document it did not keep those line breaks.

I have tried everything, and Im completely stuck.

My code is:

```
<fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell margin-right="0mm" margin-left="0mm"
                margin-bottom="0mm" margin-top="0mm"
                xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordergris" number-columns-spanned="5">
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="titoldades" 
                    space-before.optimum="0pt" space-after.optimum="0pt"
                    keep-together="always" >
                            More info:
                </fo:block>                                     
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="dades"  
                    space-before.optimum="0pt" space-after.optimum="0pt"
                    keep-together="always" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
                                            
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/Response/DataList/Data/MoreInfo"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'  '" />
                      <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'&lt;fo:block/&gt;'"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                </fo:block>                                     
            </fo:table-cell>                                
        </fo:table-row>
```

Which use a template function:

```
<xsl:template name="replace-string">
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:param name="replace"/>
<xsl:param name="with"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="text"
        select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

</xsl:template>

And the resulting text appears with the hardcoded text "<fo:block/>" instead of applying the line break.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to put the following properties inside the fo:block:

```
inefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve"
```

And then do the replace with the following:

```
<fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="dades"  
                    linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve">

                    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/Response/DataList/Data/MoreInfo"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'  '" />
                      <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'&#xa;'"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Your text saying "having problems on a part of the document where there is some lines of text with line breaks" suggests or sounds as if you have line breaks in the input XML. Yet your code tries to replace space characters with line break characters.

Comment: Yeah, the XML has line breaks, and the XSL did not keep them. Now this is keeping like the original source.